# conditions in expect bash; exit code 1 if it fails

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I am trying to make a condition for one of the unittests. I've checked other examples but they dont seem to work for me. The conditions is the following one:

```
expect -c "
spawn virsh --connect qemu:///system console ${name} --force
....
set ret 0
....      
expect {
"OK"{
  send \" \r\"
}
"FAIL"{
  set ret 1
  send \" \r\"
}
```

}

....

exit $ret

However it returns ret: unbound variable and breaks the scripts. Any idea how to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1. You use double quotes `"` to surround the whole expect program, but you also use them within the quoted program.  The simplest fix for that would be to change the outer quotes to single `'`, so start with `expect -c '`
2. In the `expect` command you need a space between each pattern and action, i.e. change `"OK"{` to `"OK" {` and similarly for the "FAIL" case.

(Actually you don't even need the quotes there, `OK {` would be fine, but they don't do any harm.)